# AEM DependencyResolutionException

Tags: maven, aem

I have a problem with single node project

[image]

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

1) POM is OK (I think)

2) I don't have settings.xml in .m2

3) ...

4) ...

5) I haven't configured Maven to perform strict checksum

6) It's not LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.scd</groupId>
<artifactId>single-node</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Node Example</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<description>Single Node Pluralsight sample</description>

<modules>
    <module>application</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <aem.host>localhost</aem.host>
    <aem.port>4502</aem.port>
    <aem.publish.host>localhost</aem.publish.host>
    <aem.publish.port>4503</aem.publish.port>
    <sling.user>admin</sling.user>
    <sling.password>admin</sling.password>
    <vault.user>admin</vault.user>
    <vault.password>admin</vault.password>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Release Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <scmCommentPrefix>[maven-scm] :</scmCommentPrefix>
                <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                <goals>install</goals>
                <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Source Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Jar Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Enforcer Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-maven</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>[2.2.1,)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <message>Project must be compiled with Java 6 or higher</message>
                                <version>1.6.0</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven IntelliJ IDEA Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
                <linkModules>true</linkModules>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Eclipse Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Clean Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Apache Felix SCR Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.20.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Private service properties for all services. -->
                            <properties>
                                <service.vendor>Adobe</service.vendor>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Installer Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Surefire Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Failsafe Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Deploy Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Apache Sling Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/repository/crx.default</slingUrl>
                    <usePut>true</usePut>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Content Package Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.24</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetURL>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Apache Felix Bundle Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Enforcer Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Dependency Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build Helper Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-dependency-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                     <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        build-helper-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.5,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            reserve-network-port
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>  
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- D E P E N D E N C I E S                                                -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
    <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.50.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Sling Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>aem-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JCR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-wcm-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>            
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I tried to run educational projects in 2 different PC, but still ran with this error

Could you help me with that?

P.S. Windows 10, AEM 6.2

Comment: The error was in the child application pom file. I show only main pom file :\. In child pom file need delete            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.scd</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I recommend pushing your code to github so it is easier to check..

Answer (score 0):

Provide dependency for scd.webapp and try doing a build .

```
<dependency>
 <groupId></groupId>
 <artifactId></artifactId>
 <version>${name.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @Dalwin Michael, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not help. I added        <dependency>
     <groupId>com.scd</groupId>
     <artifactId>single-node</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency> , but it produces new errors (ProjectBuildingExceprion and PluginManagerException).

Comment: Yes, I have error: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.24 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.24 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @

Comment: @Volodymyr did you added the plugin repository tags .?

Comment: Check this one from Adobe (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/vlt-mavenplugin.html) section #Obtaining the Content Package Maven Plugin

Comment: @VAr yes, I have -   <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.24</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetURL>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>  Its very simple project. Very strange.

Comment: @Volodymyr can you provide your complete pom.xml and project structure. so that i can help if any?

Comment: @VAr link: http://depositfiles.com/files/639yr8v5m it is small edu project. I only want use - mvn package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133391/discussion-between-var-and-volodymyr).

Comment: @Volodymyr , I have seen a dependency added in your module `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.scd</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>`
which is related to any module or maven downloading repository dependency ?
For simple sample AEM project you can check [my AEM Example Project](https://github.com/gourivar/varaem/tree/master/myrestserviceproj)

Comment: @VAr Perhaps my example is wrong. I'm learning course Fundamentals of Building from Projects in AEM on Pluralsight, this example from there. How can I thank you? And where do you learn AEM? Your example has helped me.

Comment: I have started AEM with the organization by having some basic understanding classes by the project team, There are number of examples now a days on-line have a look at them. Have an understanding of the technology stack which makesup AEM (Sling,JCR,Jackrabbit,OSGi, etc,.) Google around these topics

Comment: [Maven](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/),
[aemcq5tutorials](http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/category/tutorials/adobe-aem-cq5-tutorials/),
[cq5tutorials](http://cq5tutorials.blogspot.com/),
[blogs.adobe.com](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/),
[AEM Documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-2.html),
[Helpx Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/experience-manager.html),
[OAK](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/introduction-to-oak.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely as the maven is unable to find the corresponding repository to fetch the relevant jar files to resolve the dependencies. 
In your settings.xml, add the **Adobe Public profile**. It defines the repository that maven has to access to resolve various dependencies:

```
<!-- ====================================================== -->
<!-- A D O B E   P U B L I C   P R O F I L E                -->
<!-- ====================================================== -->
<profile>
    <id>adobe-public</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>adobe</id>
            <name>Nexus Proxy Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>adobe</id>
            <name>Nexus Proxy Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the dependency block for scd.webapp which you might have added inside the child pom.xml file inside the main project. Scd.webapp may be your parent project groupId which maven is trying to search it inside the adobe public repository which is obviously not present over there.